# Connecting a RFID-RC522 with Raspberry Pi 5

Tags: python-3, rfid, gpiozero, pi-5

I bought a new Raspberry Pi 5 for a project that has RFID-tag reading and writing functions. I tried using some old python scripts(MFRC522-python) that uses RPi.GPIO to interact with the IO pins but no luck. Since the new chip doesn't support that, I'm struggling to write my own script. I went through the [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) documentation and tried to write a script to interact with the RFID reader but it doesn't seem to work (attached code snippet). If someone can point me to a guide or a RFID-RC522 documentation that shows the device functions, I should be able to write my own code.

PS: I'm using Python. | I used the standard IO pin connection for the RC522. RF522 Module | Raspberry Pi SDA | Pin 24 / GPIO8 (CE0) SCK | Pin 23 / GPIO11 (SCKL) MOSI | Pin 19 / GPIO10 (MOSI) MISO | Pin 21 / GPIO9 (MISO) IRQ – GND | GND RST | Pin 22 / GPIO25 3.3V | 3.3V

Thanks

```
import spidev
```

import logging
import time
from gpiozero import DigitalOutputDevice

class MFRC522:
MAX_LEN = 16

```
# Proximity Coupling Device
PCD_IDLE = 0x00
PCD_AUTHENT = 0x0E
PCD_RECEIVE = 0x08
PCD_TRANSMIT = 0x04
PCD_TRANSCEIVE = 0x0C
PCD_RESETPHASE = 0x0F
PCD_CALCCRC = 0x03

# Proximity Integrated Circuit Card
PICC_REQIDL = 0x26
PICC_REQALL = 0x52
PICC_ANTICOLL = 0x93
PICC_SElECTTAG = 0x93
PICC_AUTHENT1A = 0x60
PICC_AUTHENT1B = 0x61
PICC_READ = 0x30
PICC_WRITE = 0xA0
PICC_DECREMENT = 0xC0
PICC_INCREMENT = 0xC1
PICC_RESTORE = 0xC2
PICC_TRANSFER = 0xB0
PICC_HALT = 0x50

# Status
MI_OK = 0
MI_NOTAGERR = 1
MI_ERR = 2

# MFRC522 Registers Addresses
Reserved00 = 0x00
CommandReg = 0x01
CommIEnReg = 0x02
DivlEnReg = 0x03
CommIrqReg = 0x04
DivIrqReg = 0x05
ErrorReg = 0x06
Status1Reg = 0x07
Status2Reg = 0x08
FIFODataReg = 0x09
FIFOLevelReg = 0x0A
WaterLevelReg = 0x0B
ControlReg = 0x0C
BitFramingReg = 0x0D
CollReg = 0x0E
Reserved01 = 0x0F

Reserved10 = 0x10
ModeReg = 0x11
TxModeReg = 0x12
RxModeReg = 0x13
TxControlReg = 0x14
TxAutoReg = 0x15
TxSelReg = 0x16
RxSelReg = 0x17
RxThresholdReg = 0x18
DemodReg = 0x19
Reserved11 = 0x1A
Reserved12 = 0x1B
MifareReg = 0x1C
Reserved13 = 0x1D
Reserved14 = 0x1E
SerialSpeedReg = 0x1F

Reserved20 = 0x20
CRCResultRegM = 0x21
CRCResultRegL = 0x22
Reserved21 = 0x23
ModWidthReg = 0x24
Reserved22 = 0x25
RFCfgReg = 0x26
GsNReg = 0x27
CWGsPReg = 0x28
ModGsPReg = 0x29
TModeReg = 0x2A
TPrescalerReg = 0x2B
TReloadRegH = 0x2C
TReloadRegL = 0x2D
TCounterValueRegH = 0x2E
TCounterValueRegL = 0x2F

Reserved30 = 0x30
TestSel1Reg = 0x31
TestSel2Reg = 0x32
TestPinEnReg = 0x33
TestPinValueReg = 0x34
TestBusReg = 0x35
AutoTestReg = 0x36
VersionReg = 0x37
AnalogTestReg = 0x38
TestDAC1Reg = 0x39
TestDAC2Reg = 0x3A
TestADCReg = 0x3B
Reserved31 = 0x3C
Reserved32 = 0x3D
Reserved33 = 0x3E
Reserved34 = 0x3F

serNum = []

def __init__(self, spi_bus=0, spi_device=0, spd=1000000, pin_mode=10, pin_rst=-1, debugLevel='WARNING'):
    """
    Initializes the MFRC522 RFID reader.

    Args:
    - bus (int): the SPI bus number (default 0).
    - device (int): the SPI device number (default 0).
    - spd (int): the SPI bus speed (default 1000000).
    - pin_mode (int): the GPIO pin numbering mode (default 10).
    - pin_rst (int): the GPIO pin number for reset (default -1, which sets the pin based on pin_mode).
    - debugLevel (str): the logging debug level (default 'WARNING').
    """
    # Initialize SPI communication
    self.spi = spidev.SpiDev()
    self.spi.open(spi_bus, spi_device)
    self.spi.max_speed_hz = spd

    # Initialize logger for debugging
    self.logger = logging.getLogger('mfrc522Logger')
    self.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    level = logging.getLevelName(debugLevel)
    self.logger.setLevel(level)

    # Set reset pin based on pin_mode if not specified
    if pin_rst == -1:
        if pin_mode == 11:
            pin_rst = 25
        else:
            pin_rst = 22

    # Set up reset pin using gpiozero
    self.pin_rst = DigitalOutputDevice(pin_rst, initial_value=True)

    # Initialize MFRC522 RFID reader
    self.Init()

def Reset(self):
    """
    Reset the MFRC522 chip by writing the PCD_RESETPHASE command to the CommandReg register.

    This function sends the PCD_RESETPHASE command to the MFRC522 chip, which resets its internal state
    and clears all registers. After the reset, the chip is ready to accept new commands.
    """
    self.WriteReg(self.CommandReg, self.PCD_RESETPHASE)

def WriteReg(self, addr, val):
    """
    Write a value to a register of the MFRC522 chip using SPI communication.

    This method sends a write command to the MFRC522 chip using the SPI interface, specifying the
    register address and the value to be written.

    Args:
    - addr (int): the address of the register to write to.
    - val (int): the value to write to the register.
    """
    self.pin_rst.value = False  # Stop any previous command
    self.spi.xfer2([(addr << 1) & 0x7E, val])
    self.pin_rst.value = True

def ReadReg(self, addr):
    """
    Read the value from a register of the MFRC522 chip using SPI communication.

    This method sends a read command to the MFRC522 chip using the SPI interface, specifying the
    register address from which to read the value.

    Args:
    - addr (int): the address of the register to read from.

    Returns:
    - val (int): the value read from the specified register.
    """
    self.pin_rst.value = False  # Stop any previous command
    val = self.spi.xfer2([((addr << 1) & 0x7E) | 0x80, 0])
    self.pin_rst.value = True
    return val[1]

def SetBitMask(self, reg, mask):
    """
    Sets specific bits in a register of an MFRC522 RFID module
    by performing a bitwise OR operation with the provided mask.

    Args:
    - reg (int): the register to modify.
    - mask (int): the bit mask to apply.
    """
    tmp = self.ReadReg(reg)
    self.WriteReg(reg, tmp | mask)

def ClearBitMask(self, reg, mask):
    """
    Clears specific bits in a register of an MFRC522 RFID module
    by performing a bitwise AND operation with the complement of the provided mask.

    Args:
    - reg (int): the register to modify.
    - mask (int): the bit mask to clear.
    """
    tmp = self.ReadReg(reg)
    self.WriteReg(reg, tmp & (~mask))

def AntennaOn(self):
    """
    Turns on the antenna of an MFRC522 RFID module by setting the TxControlReg register.

    If the antenna is already on, this method does nothing.
    """
    temp = self.ReadReg(self.TxControlReg)
    if (~(temp & 0x03)):
        self.SetBitMask(self.TxControlReg, 0x03)

def AntennaOff(self):
    """
    Turns off the antenna of an MFRC522 RFID module by clearing the TxControlReg register.
    """
    self.ClearBitMask(self.TxControlReg, 0x03)

def MFRC522_ToCard(self, command, sendData):
    """
    Executes a command on the MFRC522 and communicates with the tag or card.

    Args:
        command (int): The command to execute.
        sendData (list): A list of bytes to send to the tag or card.

    Returns:
        tuple: A tuple containing:
            - status (int): The status of the command execution.
            - backData (list): A list of bytes received from the tag or card.
            - backLen (int): The length of the backData list.
    """
    backData = []  # List to store response data
    backLen = 0  # Length of response data
    status = self.MI_ERR  # Default status
    irqEn = 0x00  # Interrupt request enable flag
    waitIRq = 0x00  # Wait for interrupt request flag
    lastBits = None  # Number of valid bits in last byte
    n = 0  # Number of bytes received

    # Set interrupt request and wait flags based on command
    if command == self.PCD_AUTHENT:
        irqEn = 0x12
        waitIRq = 0x10
    if command == self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE:
        irqEn = 0x77
        waitIRq = 0x30

    # Enable interrupts and reset FIFO buffer
    self.WriteReg(self.CommIEnReg, irqEn | 0x80)
    self.ClearBitMask(self.CommIrqReg, 0x80)
    self.SetBitMask(self.FIFOLevelReg, 0x80)

    # Put MFRC522 into idle state
    self.WriteReg(self.CommandReg, self.PCD_IDLE)

    # Write data to FIFO buffer
    for i in range(len(sendData)):
        self.WriteReg(self.FIFODataReg, sendData[i])

    # Start command execution
    self.WriteReg(self.CommandReg, command)

    # Set bit framing if command is transceive
    if command == self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE:
        self.SetBitMask(self.BitFramingReg, 0x80)

    # Wait for command execution (timeout)
    i = 2000
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.35)
        n = self.ReadReg(self.CommIrqReg)
        i -= 1
        # Break if interrupt request received or timeout
        if ~((i != 0) and ~(n & 0x01) and ~(n & waitIRq)):
            break

    # Clear bit framing if command is transceive
    self.ClearBitMask(self.BitFramingReg, 0x80)

    # Check for errors and update status accordingly
    if i != 0:
        if (self.ReadReg(self.ErrorReg) & 0x1B) == 0x00:
            status = self.MI_OK

            if n & irqEn & 0x01:
                status = self.MI_NOTAGERR

            # Read response data if command is transceive
            if command == self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE:
                n = self.ReadReg(self.FIFOLevelReg)
                lastBits = self.ReadReg(self.ControlReg) & 0x07
                if lastBits != 0:
                    backLen = (n - 1) * 8 + lastBits
                else:
                    backLen = n * 8

                if n == 0:
                    n = 1
                if n > self.MAX_LEN:
                    n = self.MAX_LEN

                for i in range(n):
                    backData.append(self.ReadReg(self.FIFODataReg))
        else:
            status = self.MI_ERR

    # Return response data, length, and status
    return (status, backData, backLen)

def Request(self, reqMode):
    """
    Sends a request command to a tag or card to initiate communication.

    Args:
        reqMode (int): The request mode to send.

    Returns:
        tuple: A tuple containing:
            - status (int): The status of the command execution.
            - backBits (int): The number of bits received from the tag or card.
    """
    status = None
    backBits = None
    TagType = []

    # Set the bit framing register to 0x07
    self.WriteReg(self.BitFramingReg, 0x07)

    # Append the request mode to the TagType list
    TagType.append(reqMode)

    # Send the request to the card using the MFRC522_ToCard method
    (status, backData, backBits) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(
        self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE, TagType)

    # If the status is not MI_OK or the back bits are not 0x10, set status to MI_ERR
    if ((status != self.MI_OK) | (backBits != 0x10)):
        status = self.MI_ERR

    # Return a tuple containing the status, back bits and tag type
    return (status, backBits)

def Anticoll(self):
    """
    Sends an anticollision command/Performs an anticollision algorithm to a tag or card to prevent multiple tags from responding.

    Returns:
        tuple: A tuple containing:
            - uid (list): The unique identifier of the tag or card.
            - size (int): The size of the UID in bits.
    """
    backData = []
    serNumCheck = 0

    serNum = []

    # Set the BitFramingReg to 0x00
    self.WriteReg(self.BitFramingReg, 0x00)

    # Append the PICC_ANTICOLL command and 0x20 to the serNum list
    serNum.append(self.PICC_ANTICOLL)
    serNum.append(0x20)

    # Call the MFRC522_ToCard method with PCD_TRANSCEIVE command and serNum data
    (status, backData, backBits) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(
        self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE, serNum)

    # Check if the operation was successful
    if (status == self.MI_OK):
        i = 0
        # Check if the backData has the expected length of 5 bytes
        if len(backData) == 5:
            # Calculate the XOR checksum of the first 4 bytes of the backData
            for i in range(4):
                serNumCheck = serNumCheck ^ backData[i]
            # Check if the calculated checksum matches the 5th byte of backData
            if serNumCheck != backData[4]:
                # If not, set the status to MI_ERR
                status = self.MI_ERR
        else:
            # If backData doesn't have 5 bytes, set the status to MI_ERR
            status = self.MI_ERR

    # Return the status and backData
    return (status, backData)

def CalulateCRC(self, pIndata):
    """
    Calculates the CRC value for the given input data using the MFRC522 chip.

    Args:
        pIndata (list): A list of integers representing the input data for which to calculate the CRC.

    Returns:
        A list of two integers representing the calculated CRC value.
    """

    # Clear the CRC IRQ flag and set the FIFO level to maximum.
    self.ClearBitMask(self.DivIrqReg, 0x04)
    self.SetBitMask(self.FIFOLevelReg, 0x80)

    # Write the input data to the FIFO.
    for i in range(len(pIndata)):
        self.WriteReg(self.FIFODataReg, pIndata[i])

    # Start the CRC calculation command.
    self.WriteReg(self.CommandReg, self.PCD_CALCCRC)

    # Wait for the CRC calculation to complete.
    i = 0xFF
    while True:
        n = self.ReadReg(self.DivIrqReg)
        i -= 1
        if not ((i != 0) and not (n & 0x04)):
            break

    # Read the calculated CRC value from the chip.
    pOutData = []
    pOutData.append(self.ReadReg(self.CRCResultRegL))
    pOutData.append(self.ReadReg(self.CRCResultRegM))
    return pOutData

def SelectTag(self, serNum):
    """
    Selects a tag or card for communication.

    Args:
        uid (list): The unique identifier of the tag or card.

    Returns:
        int: The status of the command execution (1 or 0).
    """
    # Initialize empty lists for the response data and the data buffer
    backData = []
    buf = []

    # Add the command byte and tag type to the buffer
    buf.append(self.PICC_SElECTTAG)
    buf.append(0x70)

    # Add the serial number of the tag to the buffer
    for i in range(5):
        buf.append(serNum[i])

    # Calculate the CRC values for the buffer and add them to the buffer
    pOut = self.CalulateCRC(buf)
    buf.append(pOut[0])
    buf.append(pOut[1])

    # Send the buffer to the tag and receive the response
    (status, backData, backLen) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE, buf)

    # Check if the response is successful and has the expected length
    if (status == self.MI_OK) and (backLen == 0x18):
        # Log the size of the response and return the first byte of the response
        self.logger.debug("Size: " + str(backData[0]))
        return backData[0]
    else:
        # Return 0 if the response is not successful or has an unexpected length
        return 0

def Authenticate(self, authMode, BlockAddr, Sectorkey, serNum):
    """
    Authenticates a tag or card for a specific block.

    Args:
        authMode (int): The authentication mode to use.
        blockAddr (int): The address of the block to authenticate.
        sectorKey (list): The key of the sector to authenticate.
        uid (list): The unique identifier of the tag or card.

    Returns:
        The status of the authentication.
    """
    buff = []

    # First byte should be the authMode (A or B)
    buff.append(authMode)

    # Second byte is the trailerBlock (usually 7)
    buff.append(BlockAddr)

    # Now we need to append the authKey which usually is 6 bytes of 0xFF
    for i in range(len(Sectorkey)):
        buff.append(Sectorkey[i])

    # Next we append the first 4 bytes of the UID
    for i in range(4):
        buff.append(serNum[i])

    # Now we start the authentication itself
    (status, backData, backLen) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(self.PCD_AUTHENT, buff)
    
    # Check if an error occurred
    if not (status == self.MI_OK):
        self.logger.error("AUTH ERROR!!")
    if not (self.ReadReg(self.Status2Reg) & 0x08) != 0:
        self.logger.error("AUTH ERROR(status2reg & 0x08) != 0")

    # Return the status
    return status

def StopCrypto1(self):
    """
    Stops the authentication process.
    """
    self.ClearBitMask(self.Status2Reg, 0x08)

def ReadTag(self, blockAddr):
    """
    Reads data from a specific block of a RFID card.

    Args:
        blockAddr (int): The block address of the RFID card to read from.

    Returns:
        If the read is successful and the received data is of the correct length, the function returns the received data as a list of 16 bytes. If the read is unsuccessful or the received data is of incorrect length, the function returns None.
    """

    # create an array containing the READ command and the block address to be read
    recvData = []
    recvData.append(self.PICC_READ)
    recvData.append(blockAddr)
    # calculate the CRC checksum for the command and block address
    pOut = self.CalulateCRC(recvData)
    # append the calculated checksum to the command and block address array
    recvData.append(pOut[0])
    recvData.append(pOut[1])
    # send the command and block address array to the RFID card and receive response
    (status, backData, backLen) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(
        self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE, recvData)
    # if response status is not OK, print error message
    if not (status == self.MI_OK):
        self.logger.error("Error while reading!")

    # if response data has length 16, print debug message and return data
    if len(backData) == 16:
        self.logger.debug("Sector " + str(blockAddr) + " " + str(backData))
        return backData
    # if response data length is not 16, return None
    else:
        return None

def WriteTag(self, blockAddr, writeData):
    """
    Writes data to a specified block address in the RFID tag.'

    Args:
        blockAddr (int): The block address where data needs to be written
        writeData (list): A list of 16 bytes of data to be written to the block

    Returns:
        None
    """

    # The buffer to be sent to the tag for writing data
    buff = []
    buff.append(self.PICC_WRITE)
    buff.append(blockAddr)

    # Calculate the CRC checksum for the buffer
    crc = self.CalulateCRC(buff)
    buff.append(crc[0])
    buff.append(crc[1])

    # Send the buffer to the tag and receive the response
    (status, backData, backLen) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(
        self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE, buff)

    # Check if the write operation was successful or not
    if not (status == self.MI_OK) or not (backLen == 4) or not ((backData[0] & 0x0F) == 0x0A):
        status = self.MI_ERR

    self.logger.debug("%s backdata &0x0F == 0x0A %s" %
                      (backLen, backData[0] & 0x0F))

    # If the initial write operation was successful, write the actual data to the tag
    if status == self.MI_OK:
        buf = []
        for i in range(16):
            buf.append(writeData[i])
        # Calculate the CRC checksum for the data to be written
        crc = self.CalulateCRC(buf)
        buf.append(crc[0])
        buf.append(crc[1])
        # Send the data buffer to the tag and receive the response
        (status, backData, backLen) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(
            self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE, buf)
        # Check if the write operation was successful or not
        if not (status == self.MI_OK) or not (backLen == 4) or not ((backData[0] & 0x0F) == 0x0A):
            self.logger.error("Error while writing")
        # If the write operation was successful, log it
        if status == self.MI_OK:
            self.logger.debug("Data written")

def Init(self):
    """
    Initializes the MFRC522 RFID reader by resetting it and configuring its registers.
    """

    # Reset the MFRC522
    self.Reset()

    # Set the timer mode and prescaler
    self.WriteReg(self.TModeReg, 0x8D)
    self.WriteReg(self.TPrescalerReg, 0x3E)
    self.WriteReg(self.TReloadRegL, 30)
    self.WriteReg(self.TReloadRegH, 0)

    # Enable the auto-timer for transmission and set the mode
    self.WriteReg(self.TxAutoReg, 0x40)
    self.WriteReg(self.ModeReg, 0x3D)

    # Turn on the antenna
    self.AntennaOn()
def Reset(self):
    """
    Reset the MFRC522 chip by writing the PCD_RESETPHASE command to the CommandReg register.

    This function sends the PCD_RESETPHASE command to the MFRC522 chip, which resets its internal state
    and clears all registers. After the reset, the chip is ready to accept new commands.
    """

    self.WriteReg(self.CommandReg, self.PCD_RESETPHASE)

def WriteReg(self, addr, val):
    """
    Write a value to a register of the MFRC522 chip using SPI communication.

    This method sends a write command to the MFRC522 chip using the SPI interface, specifying the
    register address and the value to be written.

    Args:
        addr (int): the address of the register to write to, in the range 0x00-0xFF.
        val (int): the value to write to the register, in the range 0x00-0xFF.
    """
    self.spi.writebytes([(addr << 1) & 0x7E, val])

def ReadReg(self, addr):
    """
    Read the value of a register of the MFRC522 chip using SPI communication.

    This method sends a read command to the MFRC522 chip using the SPI interface, specifying the
    register address.

    Args:
        addr (int): the address of the register to read from, in the range 0x00-0xFF.

    Returns:
        The value read from the register.
    """
    val = self.spi.xfer2([((addr << 1) & 0x7E) | 0x80, 0])
    return val[1]

def Close(self):
    """
    Close the MFRC522 chip by releasing the SPI interface and cleaning up the GPIO.

    This method closes the SPI interface used to communicate with the MFRC522 chip, releasing any
    system resources associated with it. It also releases any GPIO pins that were used to control the chip.
    """
    self.spi.close()
    self.gpio_chip_reset.close()
    self.gpio_chip_select.close()
    self.gpio_irq.close()
def SetBitMask(self, reg, mask):
    """
    Sets specific bits in a register of an MFRC522 RFID module
    by performing a bitwise OR operation with the provided mask.

    Args:
        reg (int): the register to modify
        mask (int): the bit mask to apply
    """
    # Read the current value of the register
    tmp = self.ReadReg(reg)

    # Set the desired bits using a bitwise OR operation
    self.WriteReg(reg, tmp | mask)

def ClearBitMask(self, reg, mask):
    """
    Clears specific bits in a register of an MFRC522 RFID module
    by performing a bitwise AND operation with the complement of the provided mask.

    Args:
        reg (int): the register to modify
        mask (int): the bit mask to clear
    """
    # Read the current value of the register
    tmp = self.ReadReg(reg)

    # Clear the desired bits using a bitwise AND operation
    self.WriteReg(reg, tmp & (~mask))

def AntennaOn(self):
    """
    Turns on the antenna of an MFRC522 RFID module by setting the TxControlReg register.

    If the antenna is already on, this method does nothing.

    """
    # Read the current value of the TxControlReg register
    temp = self.ReadReg(self.TxControlReg)

    # Check if the least significant two bits are already set
    if (~(temp & 0x03)):
        # If not, turn on the antenna by setting the bits using a bit mask
        self.SetBitMask(self.TxControlReg, 0x03)

def AntennaOff(self):
    """
    Turns off the antenna of an MFRC522 RFID module by clearing the TxControlReg register.

    """
    # Clear the least significant two bits of the TxControlReg register to turn off the antenna
    self.ClearBitMask(self.TxControlReg, 0x03)
    
def read_id_no_block(self):
    """
    Attempt to read the tag ID from the RFID tag.

    Returns:
        int: The tag ID as an integer, or None if the operation fails.
    """
    # Send request to RFID tag
    (status, TagType) = self.Request(self.PICC_REQIDL)
    if status != self.MI_OK:
        return None

    # Anticollision, return UID if successful
    (status, uid) = self.Anticoll()
    if status != self.MI_OK:
        return None

    # Convert UID to integer and return as the tag ID
    return self._uid_to_num(uid)
```

Comment: what's  the point of posting the code, when we don't  know how everything is connected?

Comment: I used the standard IO pin connection for the RC522. 

RF522 Module | Raspberry Pi
SDA                   | Pin 24 / GPIO8 (CE0)
SCK                   |  Pin 23 / GPIO11 (SCKL)
MOSI           | Pin 19 / GPIO10 (MOSI)
MISO           | Pin 21 / GPIO9 (MISO)
IRQ –
GND           | GND
RST                   | Pin 22 / GPIO25
3.3V           | 3.3V

Comment: please add that to the question... it does not belong in a comment ... format it as code, so thatbit displays nicely